# How can I programmatically close a FAB button list in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, floating-action-button

How can I programmatically close a FAB Button list in IONIC 3?

[image: example open FAB button list]

Comment: Looks like you just added a question and then answered it. It's not wrong if you have a good question that you know the answer will help many people but that's not your case. And btw you don't need to close you fab from the script, if the fab button HTML is correct it should close as you press the button.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto i Need This kind of Thing but i not Found solution so i thing it will help other ... thats my opinion thats why i do this

Comment: This came up in a Google search and gave me the answer I was looking for so was useful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) In HTML

<ion-fab top right #fab>
  <ion-fab-list side="bottom">
    <button ion-fab (click)="Close($event, fab)">
        <ion-icon  name="trash"></ion-icon> 
      </button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>

2) In .TS

import {  FabContainer } from 'ionic-angular';
.
.
.
Close(event, fab: FabContainer) {
    fab.close();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you added the answer exactly one minute after adding the question... Why would you do that?

Comment: @sebaferreras i Need This kind of Thing but i not Found solution so i thing it will help other ... thats my opinion thats why i do this

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, the official blog linked says "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."  So that's why!

Comment: Ionic 3 way  <br/> `<br/>@ViewChild('fab')fab : FabContainer;` `this.fab.close();`

Comment: @malwatte this was missing, thank you!